# Error 4605 trying to paste text in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I compiled code to:

1- clean all content of the active document, including header and foot;

2- copy, sequentially the content of several word files that are into a folder to the current file, inserting a page break after each file;

3- delete blank page (I would like to delete anothers blank pages, but I do not know how).

This code did run several times, but now, it gives

> error 4605

The yellow line in the code is:

```
Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
```

```vb
Sub criarRelatorio()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'desabilita mensagens de atualização

    Dim MasterDoc As String
    Dim mySource As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim endPasta As String
    Dim SeparateDoc As String
    Dim nFile As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response, MyString

    endPasta = "H:\Assessores\Pareceres\LHR\relats"

    Msg = "Deseja colar os " & nFiles(endPasta) & " arquivos que estão na pasta (" & endPasta & ") neste documento? " _
      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Isso pode demorar de 5 a 10 minutos." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      " Caso aceite, aguarde até que apareça uma mensagem confirmando a colagem dos itens."    ' Define message.
    Style = vbYesNo Or vbCritical Or vbDefaultButton2    ' Define buttons.
    Title = "Utilização de macro LHR"    ' Define title.

    ' Display message.
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
    If Response = vbYes Then    ' User chose Yes.
        GoTo aceitou ' Perform some action.
    Else    ' User chose No.
        GoTo cancelou ' Perform some action.
    End If

aceitou:
    'delete all content before starting
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument

    Set WordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    MasterDoc = ActiveDocument.Name
    Set mySource = obj.getfolder(endPasta)

    nFile = nFiles(endPasta)
    i = 0

    For Each oFile In mySource.Files
        If i < nFile Then
            Application.Documents.Open mySource & "\" & oFile.Name, Visible:=False
            Documents(oFile.Name).Activate
            SeparateDoc = ActiveDocument.Name
            Selection.WholeStory
            Selection.Expand wdParagraph
            Selection.Copy
            Documents(oFile.Name).Close
            Documents(MasterDoc).Activate
            Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
            Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
            Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next oFile

    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete

    'removing first line
    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
    Selection.MoveEnd wdLine
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveDocument.Undo
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    MsgBox "Os " & nFiles(endPasta) & " Relatórios já foram colados!", , "Atenção!!"
    Exit Sub
cancelou:
    MsgBox "Operação Não Executada", , "Cancelado"
    Exit Sub

    'habilita mensagens de atualização
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be better if you translate the dialogues into English. Few people (like me) will understand clearly, which would help a lot in the evaluation of the code.

Comment: Are you running this on a Workstation or a Server?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html

Comment: Sorry ALeXceL! Next time I will translate all my code.

Comment: Jeremy Thompson, I run this code on a workstation.

Comment: Thank you macropod! I will analyze your suggestion and try to apply it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is that you are using the clipboard, which is an OS function, inside a loop. Your VBA code executes more quickly than the clipboard can cope with, resulting in the error.

It is entirely possible to do what you are attempting without using the clipboard at all. Ranges in Word have a [`FormattedText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.formattedtext) property that can be assigned from one range to another. This effectively does the same job as copy/paste, but without invoking the clipboard.

I have edited your code to use this method but haven't edited the code after the loop. You'll need to tidy that up yourself.

```
Sub criarRelatorio()

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'desabilita mensagens de atualização

        Dim MasterDoc As Document
        Dim mySource As Object
        Dim oFile As Object
        Dim endPasta As String
        Dim SeparateDoc As Document
        Dim nFile As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response, MyString

        endPasta = "H:\Assessores\Pareceres\LHR\relats"

    Msg = "Deseja colar os " & nFiles(endPasta) & " arquivos que estão na pasta (" & endPasta & ") neste documento? " _
        & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Isso pode demorar de 5 a 10 minutos." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    " Caso aceite, aguarde até que apareça uma mensagem confirmando a colagem dos itens."    ' Define message.
    Style = vbYesNo Or vbCritical Or vbDefaultButton2    ' Define buttons.
    Title = "Utilização de macro LHR"    ' Define title.

        ' Display message.
        Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
    If Response = vbYes Then    ' User chose Yes.
       GoTo aceitou ' Perform some action.
        Else    ' User chose No.
      GoTo cancelou ' Perform some action.
    End If


aceitou:
    'delete all content before starting
    Set MasterDoc = ActiveDocument
    With MasterDoc
        .Content.Delete
        .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
    End With

        'This isn't needed. You're running the code in Word so don't need another instance
        'Set WordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set mySource = obj.getfolder(endPasta)

    nFile = nFiles(endPasta)
    i = 0

    For Each oFile In mySource.Files
        If i < nFile Then
            Set SeparateDoc = Documents.Open(mySource & "\" & oFile.Name, Visible:=False)
            MasterDoc.Content.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
            MasterDoc.Characters.Last.FormattedText = SeparateDoc.Content.FormattedText
            SeparateDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
            'replaced by lines above
            'Selection.WholeStory
            'Selection.Expand wdParagraph
            'Selection.Copy
            'Documents(oFile.Name).Close
            'Documents(MasterDoc).Activate
            'Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
            'Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
            'Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Next oFile

    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete

    'removing first line
    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
    Selection.MoveEnd wdLine
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveDocument.Undo
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    MsgBox "Os " & nFiles(endPasta) & " Relatórios já foram colados!", , "Atenção!!"
        Exit Sub
cancelou:
    MsgBox "Operação Não Executada", , "Cancelado"
        Exit Sub

    'habilita mensagens de atualização
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Timothy Rylatt for your help and your suggestion! I ran your code twice and both times the first 73 pages were blank and the headers were not pasted.

Comment: @Luiz - your question did not mention bringing across the headers, and the code in your question does nothing to bring headers or footers across. Your question is specifically about the error on pasting, which my answer solved. If you also need headers and footers you should use the code from the link in macropod's comment.

Comment: macropod, I'm using your code and it helps me almost 100%, except (I don't know why) sometimes it inserts a BreakContinuous and not a BreakNextPage. I was thinking of (instead of trying to understand what's going on) adding a few lines of code to find all occurrences of BreakContinuous and replacing it with BreakNextPage. Also, if you can, tell me how to find and delete all blank pages after the end of the document combination (I think they are caused by those who edit the text unnecessarily entering too many "enters" at the end of each text). Thank you very much in advance by your great help!